# How to get the slice of a plot3d object?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have some points and I plot the surface of them using the code below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm, colors
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

# Create a sphere
r = 1
pi = np.pi
cos = np.cos
sin = np.sin
phi, theta = np.mgrid[0.0:pi:20j, 0.0:2.0*pi:20j]
radis=np.random.normal(1,0.2,(20,20))
x = radis*sin(phi)*cos(theta)
y = radis*sin(phi)*sin(theta)
z = radis*cos(phi)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.plot_surface(
    x, y, z,  rstride=1, cstride=1, color='c', alpha=0.3, linewidth=0)
ax.scatter3D(x,y,z, c='r')

ax.set_xlim([-1,1])
ax.set_ylim([-1,1])
ax.set_zlim([-1,1])
# ax.set_aspect("equal")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Then I get the 3d plot result:
[image]

The thing I want to do is that get the image of any plane, like z=0.

Is there any method or library can cover this problem?